Устойчивое словосочетание (идиома). А правильно ли во мн. числе?
В заставке известного радиоканала звучит пафосная фраза: «Люди, ставшие примерами доблести и отваги». Можно предположить повод для выбора мн. числа слова Пример? Не множественное же число рядом стоящих слов?

Он создает обличительные фигуры, являющиеся примером блестящего
социального анализа и психологической правды.
Прочие же государства в этом отношении примером нам служить не могут.

